# IronPython Microsoft.Scripting.MutableTuple Exception

Tags: python, c#, ironpython, python-unittest, mutable

I am trying to run unit tests for a Iron Python code (Python with C#). I am facing the below error when running the unit tests. However the weird thing is that the framework runs for other python code tests. The framework is written using the unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromName and then calls the test runner.

One reason I feel the code may not be running is because of the memory exception as there are alot of data structures that have been used in this python code compared to others for which the tests are running successfully.

I have worked on changing the defaultTestLoader to loadTestsFromModule and loadtestsfromtestcase. But I still get the same error.

Can someone please help me to find a solution around this?
[Error on CMD when running tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDIai.png)
[Test Framework Code to run tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMsTJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

I faced whith the same problem in `Dynamo for Revit` application.
As i understand the count of naming variable have some memory limit.
I start to use dict instead of variables. It help me. But it is not the best way out.

[image]